# PHP Code not running through Batch File

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file, batch-file

This File(home.php) is running properly but when i am runnng this file through batch file in windows scheduler. It's not running.

```
    <?php

//error_reporting(0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test"); 

$handle = @fopen("organisation.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 20000, ",")) !== FALSE) 

 {  
 $tt="INSERT INTO upload (organization, entity, credit_limit, days) VALUES(
     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[0])."',
     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[1])."',
     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[2])."',
     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$data[3])."'
     )";
     mysqli_query($con,$tt) or (mysqli_error($con)); 

}
echo "done";

?>
```

Below is the batch file code:

```
c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "c:\xampp\htdocs\home.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how windows scheduler works, but if it's close to cronjobs in ubuntu, you should use absolut paths to files. The script is probably not executed in it's own directory.

So try this:

```
$handle = @fopen("c:\xampp\htdocs\organisation.csv", "r");
```

Also you could add:

```
echo "$tt <br>";
```

befor you execute the SQL-statment to see what the statement acually is. If you get a statment but nothing is added into your database, copy the satemant and try it manually, to see prosibble errors.

Comment: Warning is coming while executing a batch file:-  warning:fgetcsv () expects parameter 1 to be resource boolen given in line 8.

Comment: So the handle is not opening. Can you check if the permissions are all right and you got the right path?

Comment: if handle is not working in batch file then how it is running separately.

Comment: the windows scheduler probably misses the permission you have when you run it with your normal account.